# How to find the number of times if or else code has executed?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method in plain java class in my web-application. I want to get the count of if and else block execution in 5 minutes. 
How would you do it?

Comment: Use a counter. Reset it after five minutes.

Comment: Either a simple integer counter or [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Comment: @Michael That won't go beyond method-level resolution though, so it's not for if-else blocks.

Comment: @daniu Refactor the body of the `if` and the `else` to their own methods, then use AOP on those.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to get there. For example you could create a "counter" class, that gets instantiated with some class/method name. And then the method itself calls the counter whenever it is entered.

The downside of that is of course that you are now **mixing** up responsibilities. Your business method should do its *business job*. It shouldn't know or do anything about *tracking* its invocations!

So this would be a good example for using some sort of *aspect oriented* programming! Meaning: "counting" invocations is an *aspect* that ideally gets defined and "attached" to a method *without* you doing that "manually" in the method body. So, in case you are using a framework such as Spring that supports AOP, that would be the preferred option to look into.

Beyond that: it might also be possible to use some sort of *instrumentation* framework here. You see, any reasonable *profiler* should be able to give you such numbers.

Therefore the real answer is to get clear on your requirements - as there are very different options, depending on the problem you intend to solve here.

Answer (score 1):

Using a counter + a timer in the current class is dirty : mixing responsibilities as underlined by GhostCast.
Using AOP/generated proxy classes is a possibility but for such a simple requirement it seems overkill.  If you need to count the invocations for 10 or more methods, you should seriously considering these ways.

But for one method to watch I would tend to use a Observable/Observer pattern where the class that you want to watch invocation is the Observable and I would move the counter and the timer logic to reset the counter in the Observer class.
It would give this worflow :

1) The Observer registers itself to the Observable
2) the Observable invokes the Observer at each invocation
3) The Observer increments the counter consequently
4) The Observer resets the counter thanks to a timer every 5 mn

Answer (score 0):

Use static field to store the startTime, if- and elseCounters. Upon each execution check if 5mins has gone:

```
if ((System.getTimeMillis() - startTime) > (5 * 60 * 1000)) {
  reset fields;
  print out the counters;
} else {
  increase counters;
}
```